# Importando coluna do GridView para TextBox

Tags: gridview

Estou criando uma aplicação em WindowsForm. Porém, ao importar dados do GridView para o TextBox apenas uma coluna apresenta a mensagem:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: AbreviacaoCEG não é uma DataColumn nem uma DataRelation da tabela.

Print screen:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: É de muita importancia **atentar-se** para o mensagem, lendo-a **atentamente**, pois ela é **clara**. Agora a cerca da **screen** eu não tenho acesso a *URLs* do servidor, por esse motivo não sei o conteúdo da mesma, favor, caso seja código [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/267046/edit) sua pergunta e adicione o código nela. Aproveite e faça o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber como funciona a **comunidade**, caso necessite de ajuda com formatação basta acessar a [help].

Comment: Pelo erro, esse não é o nome certo da coluna. Confirma maiusculas e se está exactamente igual ao nome que colocaste no código.

Comment: Bom dia, Valeu pela ajuda, Renato Afonso. Na verdade era um alias na coluna.